# Mysites are not working after Server name changed in my Development server

Tags: sharepoint-server

I did change the servers names from UAT->Preprod .So I have changed the server name .After that  I tried to access the mysite it is not working.

Anyone face same issue like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reconfigure the My Site Host in User Profile Service Application->Setup My Sites.